# What are the differences between "object equality" created by the factory method of the companion object and case class?

Tags: scala, equality, case-class, companion-object

When comparing object equality through instances created by the factory method of the companion object, it will be false.

```
class Companion(s: String)
object Companion {
    def apply(s: String): Companion = {
        new Companion(s)
    }
}
val c1 = Companion("foo")
val c2 = Companion("foo")
println(c1 == c2) // false
```

But why will it be true when the same situation created by the case class?

```
case class Case(s: String)
val c1 = Case("foo")
val c2 = Case("foo")
println(c1 == c2) // true
```

What are the differences between those two?

Comment: `==` is not reference equality in Scala.

Comment: If you really want reference equality use `a eq b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factory methods aren't relevant. Both in your first case, and for case classes they just call the constructor and so the code can be simplified to

```
new Companion("foo") == new Companion("foo")
```

and

```
new Case("foo") == new Case("foo")
```

Because `Companion` doesn't override `equals` (or inherit from a class/trait overriding `equals`), you get `Object`'s definition which is reference equality and false for any two different instances.

`Case` overrides `equals` because it's a case class, and the implementation simply compares `s` values.

Comment: The companion doesn't override equals but Case does. This is the key. Thanks.

Comment: == between instances created from classes other than case class is reference equality, correct?

Comment: It's only reference equality if the class on the left-hand side doesn't override `equals`. Case classes are just one way to override `equals`.